# How to make criteria in AVERAGEIFS update automatically?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to make my AVERAGEIFS criteria update automatically according to the day of the year (in this case only for 2014). My original AVERAGEIFS formula works perfect ***=AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$35041,$A$2:$A$35041,">=1/1/2014",$A$2:$A$35041,"<1/2/2014")***, but I have to manually edit it for each day of the year.

I have tried modifying formulas I have seen in other posts here, but no luck so far. I want to average the values in column B (Amount) for each day in column A (Date). I have 96 time slots for each day of the year, hence the 96 entries in column A with the same date, e.g. 1/1/2014 and so on until 12/31/2014. How can I modify the formula so that it automatically adjusts the day when I drag it down?

Here is a screenshot of the data:

[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnG8H.png)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated formula below; I had misread the original question as to how your data was formatted.  You can put this formula in B2 and copy down.

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$35041,$A$2:$A$35041,">="&$A2,$A$2:$A$35041,"<"&($A2+1))
```

Your original comparison operator hardcoded a date as a string.  We can simply concatenate the value of a cell into that comparison string instead.

Granted, this will do the same calculation for each of the 96 entries for each of the days in your sheet.  You could add a second sheet for the averages with just the distinct days of the year listed in A and an average calculation in B.

EDIT 2:
If your entries in column A have fractional date information (i.e. with hours, minutes, and seconds), converting the dates to integers will drop any fractional component:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$35041,$A$2:$A$35041,">="&INT($A2),$A$2:$A$35041,"<"&INT($A2)+1)
```

Comment: The formula seemed to work, however I am worried the average values I am getting are not correct. I am having all negative values, while I know there must be positive ones too. Also, they are nearly identical. I did a comparison with the normal AVERAGE function for the first two days - there are differences. I was thinking, shouldn't the last part of the formula "<"&($A2+1)) be something like  "<"&($A2+96)) since A2+1 leads to a cell which is still 1/1/2014 and I am putting this into the calculation for the next day - 1/2/2014? I tried it, but the AVERAGE values are still very different.

Comment: `A2+1` should yield whatever the contents of `A2` is plus one (day).  you can test this by typing `=A2+1` in any blank cell and seeing what comes up.

Comment: does the average change within each day span of 96 rows?  if so, you probably have fractional date information in column A and the formula above won't work.

Comment: I just updated my original post to include a screenshot of the data under "Screenshot of data". I did the test as you said in column H and it works for the first date in H1 (from 01/01 to 01/02) but then it gets stuck on 01/02 because the value in $A3 is still 01/01 so $A3+1 will lead to 01/02 even though I want it to be 01/03. There is a different amount in Column B for each time slot for each date, i.e. 96 different amounts each day. I am trying to average those for the full days in Column F. With the above formula, the amounts in F are not correct. How can I fix this?

Comment: are there fractional dates stored in column A as well?  format the column as custom `m/d/yyyy hh:mm` -- if anything other than 00:00 shows up to the right of the date you will need to strip that out using `INT(A2)` etc.

Comment: if your data is consistent in column A with 96 entries per date, you can apply this formula in column H2 and copy down to get unique dates: `=INDIRECT("A"&(ROW()-2)*96+2)`.  the `-2` and `+2` are your offset from row "0", so if you change the row it starts on, update these accordingly.